# c++: Address will always evaluate to true error

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I wrote my own atexit method, the problem is, everything passed in is 1. When I attempted to print the address before providing it to my atexit, the compiler generated the following warning:

void dummy() will always evaluate as 'true'

```
void atexit(void(*func)(void))
{
   cerr << func << endl; // prints 1
   // store func for later
}

void dummy()
{
   cout << "dummy()\n";
}

cerr << &dummy << endl; // prints 1, generates warning
atexit(&dummy);
```

Why is it always trying to pass true instead of the address?
Note: if it matters, the real code is trying to pass the address of a class' static private member function (singleton).

**EDIT**

I don't care what the address is printed as, this is an example. What I am trying to figure out is why the address is passed as a boolean to atexit and thus is always 1.

Comment: You should call your function something else because `cstdlib` already defines an [`atexit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) function.

Comment: it is under a namespace, so it won't collide. Why doesn't anybody ever understand simple examples

Comment: cast the function pointer to void*, if your implementation supports that

Comment: Umm, `stdlib.h` defines `atexit` under the global namespace. Including `cstdlib` doesn't automatically guarantee that is no longer the case. But, by all means, feel free to ignore advice.

Comment: No, I made a namespace and added my own atexit within it

Comment: @steveo225 - Follow Balog Pal's advice: Try casting your function pointer to `void*` and printing that. It's not portable, but it will work if you are targeting Windows, or any Unix variant (e.g., Mac, Linux).

Comment: DavidHammen and BalogPal: Thank you for constructive help, I'll try that and reply a response when I get a chance

Answer (score 5):

`operator<<` for ostream doesn't have an overload that takes a function pointer, so the `bool` overload is selected. The function pointer is passed fine, it's only converted to 1 for printing (which is why the warning relates to the line where you print it, not the line where you pass it).

AFAIK there is no portable way to print a function pointer, other than to print the bytes of its object representation.

Comment: That maybe true, but printing an address does not default to printing 1 (like when I do in atexit where it is clearly not a boolean), and if I try to use 'func,' the application seg faults, because 1 is not a valid address. This isn't about printing, this is really about the address being passed as 1

Comment: @steveo225: you'll have to show real code. In your example code, `func` is not equal to `1` and it can be called no problem.

Comment: The real code is thousands of lines of code, I can show a better example, but I can't guarantee it will behave like what I am seeing.

Comment: @steveo225: then you're going to have to do some work before the question can be answered. Unless someone is able to guess what mistake you've made without seeing your real code, which happens surprisingly frequently. If you can produce an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) then people can look at what you've done wrong instead of guessing. If there's a bug somewhere in your thousands of lines of code, then for all we know it's because of memory corruption, the problem could be almost anything.

Comment: @steveo225 Passing the function pointer [does work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ddf856ec9bff24c8d8d7521318990115-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc). Your problem probably lies elsewhere.

Comment: Re *printing an address does not default to printing 1* - Printing a non-null function pointer does indeed "default to printing 1". That is all that can be printed. That does not mean the address truly is 1.

Comment: If it matters, I print address through streams all the time as a debugging mechanism, and I always get the address printed as hex (in my environment).

Comment: @steveo225: And how many of those addresses are function pointers? Printing an ordinary pointer works just fine, it's only  function pointers and the like which don't.

Comment: I don't understand the confusion; this answer says exactly what happens and why. Apparently the `<<` operator could accept either a `void*` or a `bool` type argument; the function pointer could be converted to either of these types, but only the (useless) conversion to `bool` can be done implicitly (because too many programmers are too lazy to write explicit equality tests against an appropriate null pointer), whereas the conversion to `void*` requires a cast. If you want the latter (as you obviously do), just write the cast.